# hashcode implementation in java for

Tags: java, hashcode

I`m having some trouble figuring out how to implement a working hashcode for the below example:

I have 2 classes :

```
Class A
{
} 

Class B 
{
  protected List<A> constitutingObjects;
}
```

Already overridded equal so object A equals object B if A is part of B.constitutingObects.
The issue I have is that i`m not sure how to implement the Hashcode for this.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: In the code snippet you define 2 classes, but in text you mention 2 objects. I still don't see a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Take a step back and try to tackle your bigger task in a different way.

> Already overridded equal so Class A equals Class B if A is part of B.constitutingObects

That sounds like a *very bad idea*. It's hard to tell what these objects are meant to represent, but something containing a collection isn't logically equal to an element of that collection - a shopping list isn't equal to "milk".

Don't forget that you *must* follow the requirements specified by the [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) documentation. Lots of other code will *depend* on those guarantees.

Implementing `hashCode` will basically be impossible unless you just return a constant. The hash code of two equal objects has to be equal, which means the hash code of any instance of `ClassB` would have to be equal to the hash code of *every element* of `constitutingObjects`, which means that all of those elements would have to have the same hash code. Unless instances of `ClassA` somehow "knew" what their container was, I don't see how this could be possible.

Comment: I guess the problem is actually getting to this situation. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

When defining `equals` and `hashCode` in Java, you are not testing if 2 classes are equal, you are actually testing if 2 objects of the same type (class) can be equal, according to the `equals` method or they can be in the same "bucket" (logically group of objects) according to the `hashCode`.

So, if x and y are 2 objects of type A:

```
A x = new A();
A y = new A();
```

- if `x.equals(b)` is true then `x.hashCode()` must be equal to `y.hashCode()`
- if `x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()` then `x.equals(y)` could be true or false